# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token creat indexDB

Tags: javascript

i want make IndexDB in browser google chrome 
i don't know what is mistake the code is true but i'm surprising from error

> Error:
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = notes-class.js:2
>
> app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Notes is not defined at app.js:1

this is my code :

Notes.js

```
class Notes{
dbVersion = 1;
dbName = 'myDatabase';
reverseOrder = false;
connect(){
  return new Promise((reslove, reject) =>{
    const request = indexedDB.open(this.dbName, this.dbVersion);
    request.onupgradeneeded = () => {
      let db =  request.result;
      if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains('notes')){
        db.createObjectStore('notes', {keyPath:'id' , autoIncrement: true})
      }
    }
    request.onsuccess = () => reslove(request.result);
    request.onerror = () => reject(request.error.message);
    request.onblocked = () => console.log('Storage is blocked');
  });
}}
```

app.js

```
    const NotesObj=new Notes();
NotesObj.connect();
```

notes.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>course</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/projectNote/Notes.js"></script>
    <script src="/projectNote/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the version of your Chrome browser? If you are using an older version of Chrome, it may not support class variable syntax.

Comment: “Unexpected token = notes-class.js:2” - is that the _actual_ code and error message? They do not appear to agree: did something get lost in copying the message?